# How to render react component in Leaflet popup.setContent()

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I want to render the `react` component in `Leaflet` popup as `popup.setContent(<MyCustomComponent/>)`.

Seems like I can set only `<String|HTMLElement|Function> htmlContent`.

Since, There are few user interactions in my custom component, I can't use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: create a new `div`, set it as the popup content and render your component into it with `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: Create a separate DOM element as the popup content and then render your component there as a portal: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#rendering-react-components-into-non-react-dom-nodes

Answer (score 1):

You render the CustomReactPopup component in html, pass it to a marker, and then add event listeners to your component. Perhaps this is not the best solution to the problem, but so far it has been possible to solve it only in this way. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-with-react-forked-7252c?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "./styles.css";

const GEO_POSITION = [51.5, 0];

const CustomReactPopup = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}>
      <p>CustomReactPopup</p>
      <button id="popup-button-id">Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: GEO_POSITION,
    zoom: 13
  };

  clickHandler = () => {
    console.count("click");
  };

  gtt = () => {
    const buttonEl = document.getElementById("popup-button-id");

    if (buttonEl) {
      buttonEl.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
    }
  };

  gtt2 = () => {
    const buttonEl = document.getElementById("popup-button-id");

    if (buttonEl) {
      buttonEl.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    var map = L.map("map").setView(GEO_POSITION, 13);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker(GEO_POSITION)
      .addEventListener("popupopen", this.gtt)
      .addEventListener("popupclose", this.gtt2)
      .addTo(map)
      .bindPopup(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomReactPopup />))

      .openPopup();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="map" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```